# orderBy doesn't work laravel in one table

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like to sort my data by using orderby in Laravel. Here is my code:

```
History::where('cus_id', $id)
    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')
    ->get();
```

**History table migration**

```
public function up()
{
    if(!Schema::hasTable('history')) {
        Schema::create('history', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('cus_id', 40)->nullable();
            $table->string('activity', 255)->nullable();
            $table->string('remark_id', 4)->nullable();
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('note', 255)->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}
```

the result is not according to orderby

Comment: try using the lowercase 'desc'

Comment: Can you post your create history table migration?

Comment: @EricMarcelino the results are the same, not in the order

Comment: @Peter history table migration above

Comment: @ialx what version of laravel you are using?

Comment: @EricMarcelino Laravel Framework 5.4.36

Comment: are you using any jquery or ajax to populate table?

Comment: Recheck your query by removing ```orderby``` clause and Check your ```updated_at``` column.

Comment: can you post the sample data in your table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the code you provided, I think that everything should work properly.

It's hard to understand what's happening in there with this few code, so here is what you can do:

- In the History model, please make sure that you don't have public property `$timestamps` set to `false`
- Still in the History model, add `protected $table = 'history'`.
  The default behaviour of Laravel will make Eloquent looks into the `histories` table, not `history`.
- Your migration starts with `if(!Schema::hasTable('history'))`, make sure that everything updated properly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try some alternate solution?
Use `sortbyDesc` method, I confirmed from documentation that it is available for your version of Laravel(5.4).

Here goes your code:

```
History::where('cus_id', $id)
    ->get()  
    ->sortbyDesc('updated_at');
```

Comment: This still doesn't answer why `orderBy` is not working.
To me, it would be cleaner to have everything handled in one single query than to fetch data and to map the Collection afterward.

Answer (score 0):

> The ***orderBy*** method allows you to sort the result of the query by a
>   given column. The first argument to the orderBy method should be the
>   column you wish to sort by, while the second argument controls the
>   direction of the sort and may be either asc or desc =>
>
> Here is the solution for you =>

```
 $users = DB::table('history')
                    ->where(['cus_id'=>$id])    
                    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                    ->get();
```

> If you are using model then,

```
History::where('cus_id',$id)->orderBy('updated_at','desc')->get();
```